# How to use short code in wordpress slider?

Tags: wordpress, slider, shortcode

I install wordpress slider plugin it give me a short code "`[metaslider id=85]`" to use this slider, I have this HTML code where I want to display slider

```
<div id="SliderName">


                    <img src="img/1.jpg" title="Description from Image Title" />
                    <span class="title">
                    <h1>THE CHURCH FO PENTICOST</h1><br />
                    </span>

                    <img src="img/1.jpg" title="Description from Image Title" />
                    <div class="title">
                         <h1>THE CHURCH FO PENTICOST</h1><br />
                    </div>

                    <img src="img/3.jpg" />
                    <div class="SliderNameDescription">
                    <div class="title">
                    <h1>THE CHURCH FO PENTICOST</h1><br />
                    </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

How I should Use this code "`[metaslider id=85]`" to display slider posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just add `[metaslider id=85]` in your post. (Add this when you are viewing post as normal. Do not add wher you are viewing post as HTML)

Remove the HTML you showed above from your post.

Answer (score 1):

In the Meta Slider usage options you should see 2 ways of including the slideshow in your site. The options are 'shortcode' and 'template include'.

- Use the shortcode to insert the slideshow into a post or page (using the WordPress WYSIWYG)
- Use the template include code to insert the slideshow directly into a template.

In both instances you'll want to remove the HTML you have posted as Meta Slider generates its own.